# Accepting null hypothesis given specificity

Tags: bayesian, p-value

In a population of 10000 people, there is a 2% chance that someone has cancer. The false positive rate is also 2%.

Null hypothesis: no one in the population of 10000 has cancer.

From my understanding, this can be solved by first calculating the p-value (1-0.98 = 0.02 in this case), and then calculating the probability that no one has cancer. I’m a little stuck with the second portion however - it seems like an application of Bayes theorem, but I’m not sure exactly how to formulate it. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: this is what I’m planning to do:

P(patient is actually negative) = P(patient tests negative) + P(negative|tests positive).

P(all 10000 are negative) = P(patient negative)^10000

If P(10000 negative) > 0.02, null hypothesis can be accepted

Are there any issues with this approach?

Comment: What is the question asking you to calculate?

Comment: Test the null hypothesis